# Rails6でのRSS出力方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails6でRSSを出力すべく下記の手順でコードを
書きましたが、エラーになってしまいます。
どこの手順が誤っているのかわかりません。

**articles_controller.rb**

```
def feed
  @articles = Article.all.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(6)
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
 get 'articles/feed'
```

**views/articles/feed.html.rss**

```
<rss version='2.0'>
    <channel>
        <title>1Kエクストリーム：更新情報</title>
        <link>https://www.onekextreme.com/</link>
        <description>1Kエクストリーム ブログ：新着</description>

        <% @articles.each do |article| %>
            <item>
                <title><%= article.title %></title>
                <link>https://www.onekextreme.com/articles/#{article.id}</link>
                <description><%= article.content1 %></description>
                <pubDate><%= article.created_at.strftime("%Y.%m.%d") %></pubDate>
            </item>
         <% end %>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

**ローカル環境でエラー**
`http://localhost:3000/articles/feed`

```
ArticlesController#feed is missing a template for request formats: text/html

NOTE!
Unless told otherwise, Rails expects an action to render a template with the same name,
contained in a folder named after its controller. If this controller is an API responding with 204 (No Content),
which does not require a template, then this error will occur when trying to access it via browser,
since we expect an HTML template to be rendered for such requests. If that's the case, carry on.
```

Answer (score 2):

テンプレートのファイル名を修正
`views/articles/feed.html.rss` => `views/articles/feed.rss.erb`

`config/routes.rb` の修正

```rb
get 'articles/feed', defaults: { format: :rss }
```

でどうでしょうか